# refresh rows each call in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a table in HTML.

Using JavaScript I am appending a number of table rows depending on number of my objects in an array then append cells. Which works fine, here is the code:

```js
function Build_table(filtered_data){
  filtered_data.forEach((obj => {
    // Create table rows for each object
    var row = tbody.append("tr");
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(function(x){
        // Create cell within current row.
        var cell = row.append("td");
        // give cell a value
        cell.text(x[1]);
    });
  })
);
```

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-head">Date</th>
    <th class="table-head">City</th>
    <th class="table-head">State</th>
    <th class="table-head">Country</th>
    <th class="table-head">Shape</th>
    <th class="table-head">Duration</th>
    <th class="table-head">Comments</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

But the problem is when I input search for the second time, the previous search result is still there. How can I refresh each time using pure Javascript?

Comment: How do you invoke build_table ? Whats filterd_data?

Comment: Please fix your syntax errors, change `snake_case` to `camelCase` and provide `filtered_data` to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Clear the table's rows before calling `Build_table()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to cleat the html of table body first in that case like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML='';
```

And then your old procedure as it is:

```
filtered_data.forEach((obj => {
    // Create table rows for each object
    var row = tbody.append("tr");
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(function(x){
        // Create cell within current row.
        var cell = row.append("td");
        // give cell a value
        cell.text(x[1]);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
resetTable(document.getElementById('TEMPID'));

function resetTable(tableSelector) {
  var tableTBodySelector = tableSelector.getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];
  while (tableTBodySelector.hasChildNodes()) {
  tableTBodySelector.removeChild(tableTBodySelector.lastChild);
  }
}


<table id="TEMPID">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="table-head">Date</th>
        <th class="table-head">City</th>
        <th class="table-head">State</th>
        <th class="table-head">Country</th>
        <th class="table-head">Shape</th>
        <th class="table-head">Duration</th>
        <th class="table-head">Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```